# Why is CICharField not creating database column?

Tags: django, django-models, case-sensitive, case-insensitive, django-postgresql

I am trying to use the Django CITextExtension PostgreSQL extension to create case-insensitive text fields in my database.

Concretely, here is how I am trying to use `django.contrib.postgres.fields.CICharField` in my `Expression` model to create a case-insensitive CharField in my database:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import CICharField

class Expression(models.Model):
    expression = CICharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
```

When I open the admin, however, and go into the `Expression`s area I get:

> OperationalError at /admin/dictionary/expression/
> no such column: dictionary_expression.expression

I could not find anything at all on the internet about this particular issue. **Why is `CICharField` not creating a column in my database?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be because you are using a SQLite database. Make sure you are using a PostgreSQL database.